# How to scrape website titles using google sheets?

Tags: web-scraping, google-sheets

I was wondering how can I scrape random websites article titles and links at the same time.
For example i want to scrape article titles and their links from this website to my google sheets document: https://jamesclear.com/articles
I used importXML function but unfortunately, I cant do it and I'm pretty sure I don't know how to do it.

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? "I cant do it" is pretty broad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
=importxml("https://jamesclear.com/articles","//div[@class='all-articles__list']//li")
```